# How do I uninstall Mountain Lion Server?

Tags: macos, server.app

Ok, so, here's my situation:

I had Mavericks running on my computer, and I managed to downgrade (ugh). Anyways, all my OS X server data was corrupted because OS X Server 10.8 attempted to "fix" it, when it had no idea what this 10.9 magic was. So, I executed a simple `rm -rf /Library/Server` and used AppZappr to wipe all plist's from the computer, except for the .app. However, it goes and tries to recover that data. It now cannot read any preference data for any service. How can I remove the whole thing so it thinks it is a new install?

Comment: The best way to make the machine think it is a new install is to make it a new install. Do you have backups of the machine pre-Mavericks to restore to? Or - can you simply reinstall Mountain Lion from scratch? That may be the quickest, easiest and most supported way...

Answer (score 2):

After trying numerous things, a full zap using AppZappr and deleting the /Library/Server folder allowed me to reinstall the app from the App Store and re set it up. :)